# Restart the loop if match file name doesn't exist

Tags: python, arcmap

I have the following code and for some reason I can not go back and check for next FC name. This code work great before I added if "os.path.exists()" and if, all files exist in both folders.  Please point out what is the problem. Thanks!

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
Match_FC=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Matched=Match_FC[-10:-1]
arcpy.AddMessage
env.workspace =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
output=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcList:
 if os.path.exists(fc==Matched):
    if fc[-10:-1]==Matched:
      arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, output,'','','')
 pass
```

Comment: What do you intend `fc==Matched` to do in your call to `exists`?

Comment: So I should use just a single = sign.

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.exists()` takes path on the file system and check if it exists, and you feed it with bool value.

For example:
`os.path.exists('/path/to/my/file')` returns `True` if `file` exists.

#### Edit:

I suppose you would like to do this:

```
for fc in fcList:
    if fc == Matched:
        # do sth if matched
    else:
        # do sth if not matched. If you don't need else branch just delete it, without pass
```

Comment: Can I use if "fc<>Matched: then "Pass" inside loop. Thx

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand you. What is <>? `pass` is useful here.

Comment: which I am trying to say if is not equal to.

Answer (score 0):

The code says `os.path.exists(fc==Matched)` - notice the ==. The expression `fc==Matched` can be either True or False, so you're checking whether True or False exist as paths.

They probably don't, which is why you never get inside the if.